# Easier way to assign a value to the first element of each sub list?

Tags: python, list, nested, assign

I defined a nested list like this:

```
 T=[[0 for i in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
```

Now a value is to be assigned to the first element of each sub-list, say `10`.
I tried this: `T[:][0] = 10`, but it doesn't work. I know that this can be done using a loop, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ternary `x if y else z` operator in the comprehension:

```
T = [[0 if i else 10 for i in range(4)] for _ in range(4)]
```

And since `int` is immutable, you can also do:

```
T = [[10] + [0] * 3  for _ in range(4)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Schwobaseggl

Answer (score 2):

You can use builtin [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function to assign `10` at start of each sublist.

```
>>> l = [[0 for i in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
>>> list(map(lambda x, y: x+y[1:], [[10]]*len(l), l))
>>> [[10, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Collector

Answer (score 1):

To store `10`, you can use list concatenation:

```
T=[[10]+[0 for i in range(3)] for i in range(4)]
```

Output:

```
[[10, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Or, in Python3, you can use the somewhat cleaner list unpacking `*`:

```
T=[[10, *[0 for _ in range(3)]] for i in range(4)]
```

Output:

```
[[10, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ajax

Answer (score 1):

You can try with lambda :

```
list(map(lambda x:x.__setitem__(0,10),T))
print(T)
```

output:

```
[[10, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Netplay